# ¿Esta bien la sintaxis de la Consulta a la Base de Datos?

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

Tengo esta consulta a la BD, pero no se si esta bien la sintaxis

```
    $this->db->select('rut_usu, fecha_ini, fecha_ter');
    $this->db->from('hoario');
    $this->db->where('rut_usu=',$rut_usu,'AND fecha_ini=',$fecha_ini,'AND fecha_ter=',$fecha_ter);
    $consultar = $this->db->get();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás utilizando CodeIgniter?

En ese caso tienes un error de sintaxis en:

> ```
>    $this->db->where('rut_usu=',$rut_usu,'AND fecha_ini=',$fecha_ini,'AND fecha_ter=',$fecha_ter);
> ```

La forma correcta de escribirlo es:

```
    $this->db->where("rut_usu='".$rut_usu."' AND fecha_ini='".$fecha_ini."' AND fecha_ter='".$fecha_ter."'");
```

Fíjate que los valores dentro de la sentencia SQL deben de escribirse entre comillas. Y que has utilizado ',' para concatenar, en lugar de '.'

Otra forma de escribirlo es:

```
$this->db->where('rut_usu', $rut_usu);
$this->db->where('fecha_ini', $fecha_ini);
$this->db->where('fecha_ter', $fecha_ter);
```

Y otra:

```
$array = array('rut_usu =' => $rut_usu, 'fecha_ini =' => $fecha_ini, 'fecha_ini =' => $fecha_ini);
$this->db->where($array);
```

Comment: Te lo agradezco, no estaba seguro de como debía de escribir la consulta sql en codeigniter, aunque no esperaba que a algunos les molestara que preguntara sobre ello...

Comment: De nada! Es posible que se molesten porque no has especificado que estabas usando CodeIgniter, y además puedes encontrar la información que buscabas en la documentación: [Userguide CodeIgniter](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html) En cualquier caso de todo se aprende, y para preguntar está esta comunidad no? Saludos!